# IntentService Concurrency

Tags: java, android, multithreading, intentservice

I have got a class that extends IntentService, let's say class A, and then I have got 2 more classes as class B and class C, these classes extends class A. The reason is because I want to initialize everything in class A so that code would be reused in class B and C. So class B and C's `onHandleIntent` method looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onHandleIntent(intent);
            //Specific init stuff
}
```

What I want to do is simply do some concurrency checks at class A's either constructor or `onHandleIntent`. For example when method x is being used(doesn't matter which class uses it) I would like to be able to flag this method being used. Sometimes one method schedules another thread by using `Handler.postDelayed`, so I want to make sure that flag is kept as in use until the thead work is finished.

So far it sounds like it can be done easily by shared singleton, however each of these classes have their own `AlarmManager` which extends `BroadcastReceiver`, so using a shared singleton doesn't really work as lifecycle existence of a singleton is not guaranteed.

The only solution that I can think of is using a database or local file system, which sounds quite silly. So is there another way to flag concurrent methods among different `IntentService` that are being triggered by `AlarmManager`?

To give a clear image I'd like to give an example of class A, class B and class C

```
public class A extends IntentService {
    public A(String name) {
        super(name);
        //initialise objects here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //initialise objects that uses intent here
    }

    protected synchronized void methodA() {
        //wait until flagB is free
        flagA = in_use; //Flag something as being in use here
        //change some objects here
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do some stuff with objects
                    flagB = not_in_use; //Flag something as being free here
        }
        }, (1000 * 45));// 45secs
    }

    protected synchronized void methodB() {
        if (flagA == not_in_use) {
            flagB = in_use;
             //do some stuff with objects
            flagB = not_in_use;   
        }
        else {
             //do something else
        }
}

public class B extends IntentService {
    public A(String name) {
        super("B");//Super initializes everything
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {//This will run every 30 minutes
        super.onHandleIntent(intent);
        methodA();
    }
}


public class C extends IntentService {
    public A(String name) {
        super("C");//Super initializes everything
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {//This will run every 45 minutes
        super.onHandleIntent(intent);
        methodB();
    }
}
```

So basically class B and C doesn't contain any private classes. What i want to do is just like the example above, flag things.
The problem is as I mentioned if it is just a static field, then static field might not stay in the memory as Android OS can kill anything inactive for saving memory.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is simply do some concurrency checks at class A's either constructor

Don't block in a constructor. Creating an object should be a free operation. In case of `IntentService` you would probably get an ANR because the object is constructed from within the main thread.

> or onHandleIntent

Yes. That would be a place where you could do that because that's where something actually happens. And it is executed within a background thread so blocking here is ok.

To synchronize between multiple instances of a class (including subclasses) you will need to use something `static` because that's the only common thing that multiple instances "share".

Synchronizing outside of the lifetime of your app is also (probably) not required. If your app process is killed and restarted from `AlarmManager` you would have a new singleton to work with. Anything that happened before is dead and so nothing can happen in parallel.

For example synchronize using the `.class` object of A

```
public class AService extends IntentService {
    public AService() {
        super("AService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        synchronized (AService.class) {
            // magic happens here.
        }
    }
}


class BService extends AService {
    void foo() {
        synchronized(AService.class) {
            // we can't be in here if another intentservice is within above block.
        }
    }
}
```

That does work as long as those services are running within the same app process (i.e. every simple app that does not define extra processes). `static` is globally accessible everywhere in the app.

External locking using e.g. the filesystem would be required if you have multiple processes since they can't access each other's objects at all.

besides `synchronized`, look into [`java.util.concurrent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) for more powerful / better ways of synchronizing. E.g. `` `Semaphore `` and [`ReentrantLock`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) (roughly equivalent to `synchronized`)

> I want to make sure that flag is kept as in use until the thead work is finished.

If you app is killed, you'll have to restart the work if it did not finish. So keeping a "work-progress-flag" beyond the lifetime of your app makes no sense. And `static` (e.g. your singleton) works fine while it is running.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what i was asking. As I mentioned I have got Handler.postDelayed().

So for foo() method it will simply end but later on delayed thread may be triggered at the same time as another method running.

Comment: I don't understand your code / thread structure & concurreny requirement to give any specific advice but you would typically use all the regular concurrency utilities. `Handler.post..` will typically move execution into the main thread (unless you use `HandlerThread`) and you should never block there. So be careful. Try adding some code that explains what you want to do.

Comment: I added an example now.